# How to replace a table variable in T-SQL 2008 string contatenation

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a UDF running in SQL 2000 that uses a table var to return a comma delimited string from several rows of data:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ReturnVisitsTaskNos]
   (  @MainlinePlanID int )
   RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS
   BEGIN
      DECLARE @TaskNoTable table
         (  TaskNo varchar (15)  )
      DECLARE @TaskList varchar(1000)
      SET @TaskList = ''
      INSERT INTO @TaskNoTable
         SELECT TaskNo
         FROM MainlinePlanTask
         WHERE MainlinePlanID = @MainlinePlanID
      IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
         UPDATE @TaskNoTable
            SET @TaskList = ( @TaskList + TaskNo + ', ' )
      RETURN substring( @TaskList, 1, ( len( @TaskList ) - 1 ))
   END
```

Is it possible to replace the table var code with something faster now that it is running on SQL 2008?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see where you are using a cursor...are you calling your function inside of one?

Comment: Sorry... should have said using table.. edited :)

Comment: 2000 OR 2008? The title and tags say one thing, the question another...

Comment: @Martin: I think that this is a db that was probably upgraded from 2k and the OP is trying to refactor some of the original functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't vouch for the performance but if you use the [FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) clause [like this](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/concatenate-using-xml-path.aspx) you will definitely get cleaner T-SQL in the function you have, without a temp table and cursor.

From the article:

> Here is a very simple t-sql sample
>   using FOR XML PATH() in order to sql
>   concatenate strings values as a sample
>   sql concatenation in MSSQL.

```
SELECT
  STUFF(
    (
    SELECT
      ' ' + Description
    FROM dbo.Brands
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
  ) As concatenated_string
```

Your updated function might look somethign like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ReturnVisitsTaskNos]
   (  @MainlinePlanID int )
   RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS
   BEGIN

    RETURN
      SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT
      TaskNo + ', '
    FROM MainlinePlanTask
    WHERE MainlinePlanID = @MainlinePlanID
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 0, ''
  ) As concatenated_string

   END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ReturnVisitsTaskNos]
   (  @MainlinePlanID int )
   RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS
   BEGIN
      DECLARE @TaskList varchar(1000)

      SET @TaskList = ''

      SELECT @TaskList = ( @TaskList + TaskNo + ', ' )
      FROM MainlinePlanTask
      WHERE MainlinePlanID = @MainlinePlanID

      RETURN substring( @TaskList, 1, ( len( @TaskList ) - 1 ))
   END
```